# testing menu_main.xml (Android)

Tags: android, unit-testing, menu, menuitem

I'm attempting to write unit tests for a very simple app.  Here is the menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh" android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

App runs fine, both items show up.  MainActivity.xml can clearly find them because

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

works just fine.

I have unit tests that descend from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, one of which checks the menu_main.xml.

```
public void testSettingsMenuItemExists() {
    Object view = activity.findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    assertNotNull("Settings menu item does not exist", view);
}
```

`R.id.action_settings` obviously exists because the code compiles, but when the tests run, they do not find item.  They do find elements from activity_main.xml.  I've tried getting the action bar via `activity.getActionBar()`, it is null.  I thought maybe the action bar was owned by the application, not the activity, but Applications don't even have `getActionBar()`.

How do I find menu items so I can test them in unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare activity class with theme in Manifest file which have action bar default like..

```
 <activity          
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"/> 

then you can get the action bar and it will not null.
```

Comment: But the action bar exists and is usable, it's just not found by the test code.  The application itself does have a theme.



`<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`